# Full Install Windows Server 2008

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

If I install [Windows Server 2008 R2 Evaluation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/dd459137.aspx) would there be any limitations to the software?  We need a temporary Active Directory Server for maybe 2-3 weeks and have no desire to buy another Windows Server account.  It appears unrestricted, and Active Directory could also be installed for free, right?

Comment: While I don't think it would prevent you from doing whatever you need to do, using the software at all in a production environment would likely be breaking the license agreement.  Legally, it would be no different to using a full unlicensed copy for a few weeks. What do you need such a short-term server for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  The Eval will provide what you need for the limited duration.

Comment: +1 Deleted my identical answer.  The only limitation will be based on the Edition of 2008 R2 you choose.  For instace, the Web edition cannot use the Active Directory Domain Services role. See this Microsoft [Edition Comparison by Server Role](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/r2-compare-roles.aspx) for details.